# Docker Publish ASP.NET Core with ReactJS

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I am creating a ReactJS project that use ASP.NET core to run SPAProxy. I have been following this [Quickstart guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-tools-react?view=vs-2022)  to create a base project and try to publish it to Dockerhub to see how the client code runs on the same server as the ASP.NET Core code (the change in Dockerfile is made according to the instruction for Linux container). However it has not been working as expected when I try to run the published image, as the log record only stop at this step:

```
2023-07-04 12:22:50 warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
2023-07-04 12:22:50       Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
2023-07-04 12:22:50 warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
2023-07-04 12:22:50       No XML encryptor configured. Key {9aff965f-0314-4b69-b047-1383abc2ab7c} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
2023-07-04 12:22:50 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
2023-07-04 12:22:50       Now listening on: http://[::]:80
2023-07-04 12:22:50 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-07-04 12:22:50       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2023-07-04 12:22:50 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-07-04 12:22:50       Hosting environment: Production
2023-07-04 12:22:50 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-07-04 12:22:50       Content root path: /app/
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev curl libxi6 build-essential libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev curl libxi6 build-essential libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SampleNETCoreReact/SampleNETCoreReact.csproj", "SampleNETCoreReact/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SampleNETCoreReact/SampleNETCoreReact.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SampleNETCoreReact"
RUN dotnet build "SampleNETCoreReact.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SampleNETCoreReact.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SampleNETCoreReact.dll"]
```

Is there anything I should configure in the optional setting when deploying the container? Or should I follow the container target OS to be the same as my local machine which is Windows?

Comment: Add your dockerfile and entrypoint.sh if you have

Comment: @Mate I have the Dockerfile used to build the image, which is basically the same as in the provided guide. How can I add that in optional setting when run the image?

Comment: You could use a docker-compose.yml file or  set env vars when run `docker run --env VAR1=value1 --env VAR2=value2`

Comment: So far it's still not working as expected

Comment: Could you add more detail regarding "not working as expected" ?   I tried the code with one change: a) On program.cs comment app.UseHttpsRedirection(); .  Then run `docker run -p 8081:80  --name {yourContainerName} -it  {youImageName}` and works ok when navigate http://localhost:8081

Comment: @Mate Ah thank you. I was trying to find a way to let it automatically bind a port and have the URL available on log, so since I couldn't see it I assume that it's not working. Do you know a way to bind the port with the host or make the https redirect available?

Comment: Great.  automatically bind a port => docker-compose file.  Log more info => set debug in appsettings.json . https => self signed cert or letsencrypt or some cert to your site